# Eclipse RCP: Controls not visible in dialog

Tags: java, dialog, eclipse-rcp

I'm having a few troubles with the dialogs in the eclipse rcp. I wish to have a dialog which shows me a MasterDetailBlock to manage an arbitrary amount of entities shown in a table on the master part with their corresponding DetailPages shown in the detail part. As of now, this is done using a View, but a non-modal dialog seems more fitting for this.

At first, I tried the naive way of just taking the code from the view und put it into the dialog, with a few modifications due to the difference between view and dialog creation. However, most controls were missing. A search on Google, the eclipse forums and here on Stackoverflow did not bring a solution for this. After checking these sites for the solution, I tried to understand what's happening by stepping through the code with the debugger, but that didn't help me either.

The following Code should show a dialog containing section in which a button should be displayed. However, it doesn't:

```
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {

    parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

    Section section = toolkit.createSection(parent, ExpandableComposite.EXPANDED | ExpandableComposite.TITLE_BAR);
    section.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    section.setText("Section");
    section.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    Button test = toolkit.createButton(section, "test", SWT.PUSH);
    test.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    test.setVisible(true);

    section.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT);
    return parent;
}
```

The result of this is:

[image: Result of above Code, the button "test" is missing]

However, as a MasterDetailBlock needs a form, I'll provide this Code as well:

```
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {

    parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

    form = new ScrolledForm(parent);
    form.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    form.getBody().setLayout(new FillLayout());
    Composite formComposite = toolkit.createComposite(form.getBody());
    formComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,true));

    Section section = toolkit.createSection(formComposite, ExpandableComposite.EXPANDED | ExpandableComposite.TITLE_BAR);
    section.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    section.setText("Section");
    section.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    Button test = toolkit.createButton(section, "test", SWT.PUSH);
    test.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    test.setVisible(true);



    section.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT);
    return parent;
}
```

Just a slight modification by adding a form to the dialog and everything goes on the form. However, the result looks like this:

[image]

I'm afraid I'm missing something obvious here. As I said, searching didn't bring any enlightment and stepping through the code didn't help either. My last resort "trying stuff to see what happens and try to understand that" didn't help much, as the results didn't change from the ones already posted.

So, do I miss something? (Which I think it is)
If you can provide me a link to show me what's wrong (or anything from your experience as well), I would appriciate that.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a

```
section.setClient(test);
```

missing. Moreover, you should have this when using a Form and section is expandible:

```
protected final IExpansionListener expansionListener= new ExpansionAdapter()
{
  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public void expansionStateChanged(ExpansionEvent e)
  {
    ScrolledForm form = ...; //your scrolled form goes here
    form.layout(new Control[] {(ExpandableComposite) e.getSource()}, SWT.ALL | SWT.CHANGED);
    form.reflow(true);
  }  
};

...

section.addExpansionListener(expansionListener);
```

Instead of the button `test` you should add a `Composite` which contains the button. Each section can have only one client.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I suspected it would be something simple. I'm sorry for the late reply though, normally I'm faster.